# Organize a one transaction for 2 different trasnaction managers(in 2 different APIs) with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have faced with a problem when integrating 2 different APIs in my application. The problem is that they are using different spring transaction managers with different data sources (MSSQL) & transaction templates. Spring tranasction managers are created programmatically not with beans.

Here is the snippet of the method:

```
public void f(){
     ...
     getManager().deployWorkingCopy(userId, toDeploy); //API1, TransactionManager1, DataSource1

     List<User> users = umApi.loadAllUsers();
     List<Group> groups = umApi.loadAllGroups();

     for(User user : users){
        umSynchronization.synchronizeUser(user); //API2, TransactionManager2, DataSource2
     }

     for(Group group : groups){
        umSynchronization.synchronizeGroup(group); //API2, TransactionManager2, DataSource2         
     }
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to execute those queries in one transaction? How?

Comment: AFAIK, if your data sources and database drivers supports distributed transactions and Two-Phases commit, it is possible, in general.